# How to serialize a dictionary object created from tensorflow array

Tags: python, tensorflow, flask

I have created a dictionary object by looping through a **tensorflow 2D Array**. Now I need to send this dictionary object as a response to and AngularJS based application. I'm using **Python Flask** to create my backend. However when I'm using **jsonify** function, I'm getting following exception :

```
TypeError: Object of type float32 is not JSON serializable
```

Below is a snippet of how I'm creating the dictionary object :

```
 with tf.Session() as sess:
    # Feed the audio data as input to the graph.
    #   predictions  will contain a two-dimensional array, where one
    #   dimension represents the input image count, and the other has
    #   predictions per class
    softmax_tensor = sess.graph.get_tensor_by_name(output_layer_name)
    predictions, = sess.run(softmax_tensor, {input_layer_name: wav_data})

    # Sort to show labels in order of confidence
    top_k = predictions.argsort()[-num_top_predictions:][::-1]
    result = {}
    for node_id in top_k:
      human_string = labels[node_id]
      score = predictions[node_id]
      result[human_string] = score

    return result
```

And this code snippet is called by following controller :

```
    @app.route("/predict")
    def predict():   
        data = label_wav('static/tensorflow/0a2b400e_nohash_0.wav','static/tensorflow/conv_labels.txt','static/tensorflow/my_frozen_graph.pb','wav_data:0','labels_softmax:0',3)
        print(data) ## prints : {'left': 0.970138, 'yes': 0.02154522, '_unknown_': 0.0038029249}
        return jsonify(data), 200
```

Can someone tell me how to serialize a dictionary object?

Comment: Use a list comprehension on the returned data. I can't see the object in your data, but the list stored against the key: `[float(item) for item in whatever]`. This is actually a bit of a pain that I've not found a way around with numpy and serialization. `.astype(float)` on the array won't get round it.

Answer (score 0):

float32 is not built-in type in python, which is an extended class. To serialize user-define class, you can code like this:

```
import json

class CJSONEncoder(json.JSONEncoder):
    def default(self, obj):
        if isinstance(obj, tf.float32):
            return ...
        else:
            return json.JSONEncoder.default(self, obj)

def json_dumps(data):
    return json.dumps(data, cls=CJSONEncoder)
```

Actually I have never used tensorflow before, which I searched google just now, and got this:

```
import tensorflow as tf

def convert_to_float(m):
    sess = tf.Session()
    with sess.as_default():
        ret = float(str(m.eval()))
    return ret
```

In my environment, it shows:

```
>>> m = tf.constant(1.1, dtype=tf.float32)
>>> sess = tf.Session()
>>> with sess.as_default():
...   ret = float(str(m.eval()))
...
>>> print(ret)
1.1
```

I don't know whether it's legal, but hope it helps.

Comment: Is there a short way, like if I can convert float32 to a python type float object or something?

Comment: @Paras I don't know whether it's legal, but hope it helps.